# Form ActiveX control OnAction to call procedure within class

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm creating a treeview on an Access 365 form.  To keep my form code simple, and as I'll be using the treeview on a couple of forms I moved the code into a class module.

The treeview has a right-click event so that new nodes can be added through a pop-up menu.
The problem I'm having is using the `OnAction` property of my menu control to execute a procedure that is within the class.  It works fine if the procedure is in a normal module, but then I have to pass a class reference to the module so I can access variables held within the class.

Basically I want my `OnAction` to be something like one of the lines of code below:

```
txtBox.OnAction = "Me.AddNewNode"
txtBox.OnAction = "MyClass.AddNewNode"
```

To create a Minimal, Reproducible Example:

- Create a table called **Table1** and add these fields:

  - **ID**  - (PK, AutoNumber)
  - **Desc** - (Short Text)
  - **ParentID** - (Number)

Add some data to **Table1**:
[image]

- Create a form called **Form1** and add the *Microsoft TreeView Control, version 6.0* ActiveX control.  Call the control **TreeView0**
- Open the VBE and add these references:

  - **Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 (SP6)** (should be added when the treeview is added).
  - **Microsoft Office 16.0 Access database engine object**
  - **Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library**
- Create **Class1** class module and add this code (hopefully the problem line is obvious):

```
Private rst As DAO.Recordset
Private WithEvents TV As MSComctlLib.TreeView
Const KeyPrfx As String = "X"

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDC Lib "user32" _
                           (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32" _
            (ByVal hDC As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32" _
                        (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hDC As Long) As Long

Public Property Set TreeViewControl(ByRef Value As MSComctlLib.TreeView)
    Set TV = Value
End Property

Public Sub OpenRecordSet(SQLString As String)
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordSet(SQLString)
End Sub

Public Sub CreateRightClickMenu()
    Dim txtBox As CommandBarComboBox
    On Error Resume Next
        CommandBars("LocationTVMenu").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    With CommandBars.Add("LocationTVMenu", Position:=msoBarPopup)
        Set txtBox = .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlEdit)
        txtBox.Caption = "New Location Name:"
                                       '   **********************************************
        txtBox.OnAction = "AddNewNode" '<< ***Call procedure within this class module.***
                                       '   **********************************************
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub AddNewNode()
    MsgBox "Node added!"
End Sub

Public Sub LoadTreeView()
    Dim nodeKey As String
    Dim nodeParent As String
    Dim nodeText As String
    
    TV.Nodes.Clear
    rst.MoveFirst
    Do While Not rst.BOF And Not rst.EOF
        nodeKey = KeyPrfx & CStr(rst.Fields("ID"))
        nodeParent = KeyPrfx & CStr(rst.Fields("ParentID"))
        nodeText = rst.Fields("Desc")
        If Nz(rst.Fields("ParentID"), 0) = 0 Then
            With TV.Nodes.Add(, , nodeKey, nodeText)
                .Tag = rst.Fields("ID")
            End With
        Else
            With TV.Nodes.Add(nodeParent, tvwChild, nodeKey, nodeText)
                .Tag = rst.Fields("ID")
            End With
        End If
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub TV_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, _
                       ByVal x As stdole.OLE_XPOS_PIXELS, ByVal y As stdole.OLE_YPOS_PIXELS)
    If Button = 2 Then
        Dim nodX As Node
        ConvertPixelsToTwips x, y
        Set nodX = TV.HitTest(x, y)
        If Not nodX Is Nothing Then
            With CommandBars("LocationTVMenu")
                .Controls("New Location Name:").Text = vbNullString
                .ShowPopup
            End With
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ConvertPixelsToTwips(ByRef x As stdole.OLE_XPOS_PIXELS, _
                                 ByRef y As stdole.OLE_YPOS_PIXELS)
    Dim hDC As Long, RetVal As Long, TwipsPerPixelX As Long, TwipsPerPixelY As Long
    Const LOGPIXELSX = 88
    Const LOGPIXELSY = 90
    Const TWIPSPERINCH = 1440
 
    hDC = GetDC(0)
    TwipsPerPixelX = TWIPSPERINCH / GetDeviceCaps(hDC, LOGPIXELSX)
    TwipsPerPixelY = TWIPSPERINCH / GetDeviceCaps(hDC, LOGPIXELSY)
    RetVal = ReleaseDC(0, hDC)
    x = x * TwipsPerPixelX:  y = y * TwipsPerPixelY
End Sub
```

- Add this code to the userform:

```
Private MyClass As Class1

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set MyClass = New Class1
    With MyClass
        Set .TreeViewControl = Me.TreeView0.Object
        .OpenRecordSet "Select ID, Desc, ParentID FROM Table1"
        .LoadTreeView
        .CreateRightClickMenu
    End With
End Sub
```

I've tried various versions of calling the procedure, but nothing has worked so far.  No error messages (didn't expect any) - it just doesn't fire the `AddNewNode` procedure.

---

**Edit:**
I've got a workaround which is working.  Not ideal, but this is a personal project so can rewrite as many times as I like.  I haven't added as an answer as I don't think it's the best way to go about it.

- I moved `Private MyClass As Class1` from the userform to a normal module and made it public.
- Added a Property to `MyClass` so I can get a reference to the recordset in the normal module.
- Added this procedure to the normal module:

```
Public Sub AddNewNode()
    With MyClass.RecordSetReference
        .AddNew
        .Fields("Desc") = CommandBars("LocationTVMenu").Controls("New Location Name:").Text
        .Fields("ParentID") = MyClass.TreeViewControl.SelectedItem.Tag
        .Update
    End With
    MyClass.LoadTreeView
End Sub
```

Now I just need the treeview to expand any nodes that were expanded before the treeview was reload.

Comment: I hope I'm wrong, but I don't think you can get away from this, it has to be on a standard module. But you can make the standard module a wrapper class, holding a private `Class1` field exposing it via a property get to the form. The subs will then have access to it, but unfortunately you will not be able to handle any class events.

Comment: @KotasK I'm hoping you're wrong to :)  I did find this post [VBA outlook call method with On.Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25892447/vba-outlook-call-method-with-on-action) which suggested using an event handler on the textbox.  So I added `Private WithEvents EditControl As CommandBarComboBox` to the class, and `Set EditControl = txtBox` below my `OnAction` line (cont...)

Comment: Unfortunately this only exposes a Change event:  `Private Sub EditControl_Change(ByVal Ctrl As Office.CommandBarComboBox)`.  With this I could add the text for a new node, press enter and when I clicked on the original node again the procedure in the class fired, but there's no `AfterUpdate` event.

Comment: Have you set the relevant events to `[Event Procedure]` on the control? Else they just won't fire.

Comment: @ErikA I don't think I can - the text box (`msoControlEdit`) is on the popup menu that's created when the form loads (`MyClass.CreateRightClickMenu`).  There isn't a static control for me to get to the event property - I'd have to write something like `txtBox.Events...erm...AfterUpdate, = "[Event Procedure]"` in the code.

Comment: I replicated the issue with the `Change()` event. By the way there's no need for an additional control, you can change `txtBox` to `Private WithEvents`, but it's a flawed solution. Updating the table directly and rebuilding the tree is out of the question?

Comment: Why the `..erm..`? Just `txtBox.OnAfterUpdate = "[Event Procedure]"` would do. But As Kostas K said, you'd also need to have a `Private WithEvents` there, you always need a global reference if you want to handle events. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49444091/7296893) for a basic example on how to work with events and classes.

Comment: Morning. @ErikA - the erm was because I wasn't sure of the syntax.  I tried assigning the event procedure to the control using `txtBox.OnAfterUpdate....` when it's created in the `CreateRightClickMenu` procedure, but I get `Method or data member not found`.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Ah, it's a commandbarcombobox, that indeed does not have an `OnAfterUpdate` nor an `AfterUpdate` event, only a `Change` event

Comment: @ErikA - you're not meant to say that!  You're meant to give me a perfect solution that I can just copy and paste straight into my project!  :)  Ah well, I guess Christmas was last month so no miracles this month.  Looking like I might have to find & use a different method.

Comment: @KostasK. No, I couldn't give the user direct access to the table.  Before we knew it cats would start getting on with dogs, wars would break out across the globe.... it's just too dangerous.  I'm not sure what you mean by "no need for an additional control" - where else can the user add the text for the new node?

Comment: I was referring to the `EditControl` and `Set EditControl = txtBox`.

Comment: Purely a train of thought: place your sub AddNewNode() in the code of the form, place a Sub in a module which has the line -- CallByName YourForm, "AddNewNode", VbMethod -- and call this Sub with your onaction

Comment: Since you only display a textbox, I would ditch the command bar entirely and instead I would display an ```InputBox``` when the right-click occurs. You could then use the ```CommandBars.ActionControl``` to get position of the selected item in the tree.